# C# Delegates to methods with different optional parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, optional-parameters

I know that I can declare delegates that have default constant parameters such as:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(int x, int y = 5);
```

and then call it anywhere with any method that matches the signature.

Ok, I've got LOTS of methods declared like this way:

```
public Something FirstMethod(float val = 10, int skip = 0){ ... return sth; }
public Something SecondMethod(float val = 20, int skip = 0){ ... return sth; }
public Something ThirdMethod(float val = 5, int skip = 0){ ... return sth; }
```

... this list goes up all the way down, anyway, they all have that signature structure. The point here is that, they all have floating point argument, that defaults to something different.

Then, I want to create a delegate that will point to one of these methods:

```
delegate Something ProblematicDelegateType(<<WHAT WILL GO HERE>>);
ProblematicDelegateType myFunc;
if(someValue == someParameter){
    myFunc = FirstMethod;
}else if(...){
    myFunc = SecondMethod;
}else...
...
}

myFunc();
myFunc(skip:100);
```

I want to be able to call `myFunc` both parameterless or with the `skip` parameter. In this part of code, the first parameter, `val`, is NOT used. (they are used elsewhere).

What will go to the delegate's argument list? I want to preserve *that method's* default `val` argument, whatever it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your `myFunc` will leave out the `val` parameter entirely, always using the default for whichever method you're ultimately calling, correct?

If so, this should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
delegate Something ProblematicDelegateType(int skip = 0);
ProblematicDelegateType myFunc;
if (someValue == someParameter) {
    myFunc = skip => FirstMethod(skip: skip);
} else if (...) {
    myFunc = skip => SecondMethod(skip: skip);
} else ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: that one DOES work, but is there a better, more formal/modular way of doing it? I'm searching for something that I don't add `skip => Method(skip:skip);` and just be able to 'somehow' call the method pointed by myFunc directly, without wrapping another lambda around. of course, if it's possible :)

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu: That's not possible. The methods `FirstMethod`, `SecondMethod`, etc _must_ be called _explicitly_ somewhere if you want to use some default arguments, because only at those call sites are the default arguments inserted by the compiler. So the only way is to wrap around them

Comment: ok then, I'll be continuing with the wrapping. but still don't wonder why it can't be done, as the signature is 'hard coded', no generics or casts of types anywhere, and if the compiler knows the exact order and type of parameters, there logically should be a way into that. but i'll be using the wrapper anyway.

Comment: Because optional arguments are determined at compile-time, not run-time.  When you write MyDelegate(1); the compiler generates a call to MyDelegate(1, 5);.  It doesn't know what the actual delegate will be at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda to bind the value that you want.  Default values are effectively overloads that have bound the value you desire to the function parameter.  Since you have the various if's separating out the functions, just pass around a delegate to a function that only takes a integer.

In other words,

```
delegate Something ProblematicDelegateType(int skip = 0)

//...

ProblematicDelegateType myDelegate;
if (someCondition)
  myDelegate = (_1) => FirstMethod(10, _1);
else if (someOtherCondition)
  myDelegate = (_1) => SecondMethod(20, _1);
```

and so on..

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to touch the other argument (the first one) of the method I'm invoking.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement that the delegate have an optional parameter that varies depending on the method it invokes can't be done. Optional parameters are implemented by rewriting the call site of the method when it is compiled. If the method the delegate points to is determined at run-time what would it write at compile-time? Eric Lippert's series on [optional arguments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx) is very enlightening.

However, you could also look into using reflection to get the default value. Use MethodInfo.GetParameters() to get the parameter info and [ParameterInfo.DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0acewhc.aspx) to get the default value.

Comment: i see now.. but I don't want to go into reflection, i'd just go with the wrapper solution.